# PageRank score computing

Tags: python, graph, edges, pagerank, weighted-graph

I'm currently working on the TextRank algorithm, which uses PageRank.
I was wondering how does PageRank take the edge weight into account when calculating the scores?

I'm working with Python to implement my textrank algorithm, can I use the pagerank Python function to compute the score of the nodes even though my graph is weighted (and the edge weight is important)?

Answer (score 1):

[PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) actually works using a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

You can find more details about it [in this paper](http://web.mst.edu/~gosavia/page_rank_model.pdf) (the whole theory is way too long to be explained here).